# iPad SQLite3 fails INSERT query

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, permissions

I am currently trying to simply insert a new row into my SQLite3 database on my iPad. I have done it multiple times before in other apps and just copied the code. The copied `SELECT` queries work fine, but if I try to `INSERT`, it fails at `== SQLITE_DONE`

This is how I try to insert into the database:

```
NSString *databaseName = @"Waypoints.sql";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO Waypoints (id, name, alt, ias, temp, tas, wd, ws, gs, mt, mh, dist, time, fuel, fuelrate) VALUES (%d,'New...','','','','','','','','','','','','','');", [self numberOfWaypoints]];
    NSLog(@"Statement: %@", statement);
    const char *sqlStatement = [statement cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            NSLog(@"DATABASE: Adding: Success");
        else
            NSLog(@"DATABASE: Adding: Failed");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Error. Could not add Waypoint.");
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

If I run this code on the press of a button, it outputs `DATABASE: Adding: Failed` in the console.

The NSLogged statement looks like this:

> INSERT INTO Waypoints (id, name, alt, ias, temp, tas, wd, ws, gs, mt, mh, dist, time, fuel, fuelrate) VALUES (2,'New...','','','','','','','','','','','','','');

Which works perfectly fine if I paste it in the terminal (connected to same database file).

This brings me to the conclusion: what could be causing this problem?
I thought of maybe write permissions to the file. Could be it, but it's not in the bundle but already copied to the documents folder on the device.

Please help to how I can get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried using NSUTF8StringEncoding for your cStringUsingEncoding ?

Comment: ...or printing NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(database)]);. Maybe this could point you in the right direction

Comment: @IgnacioInglese, ah thanks for that errmsg tip! It says the `database is locked` Anytips? Oh, and please convert your comments into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using NSUTF8StringEncoding for your **cStringUsingEncoding** or printing

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(database)]);
```

Glad to see you could find your error with this.

Comment: See my answer as to how I finally solved the problem. But Ignacio lead me to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By following the tip from @IgnacioInglese by printing out the error with `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_errmsg(database)]);` I found that the database is locked.

I found that I made a rookie-error by return a value in a method before closing the database. Fixing that solved my problem.